# How can I properly retrieve the virtual properties of my Data object with foreign keys?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make this work:

```cs
namespace DataService.Domain {

    public class Death {

        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10)]
        public string PersonId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 4)]
        public string DeathYear { get; set; }


        [NotMapped]
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace DataService.Domain {

    public class Work {

        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10)]
        public string TitleId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10)]
        public string PersonId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
        public string Job { get; set; }


        [NotMapped]
        public virtual Title Title { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace DataService.Domain {

    public class Person {

        public Person() {
            Works = new HashSet<Work>();
        }

        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 4)]
        public string BirthYear { get; set; }


        [NotMapped]
        public virtual ICollection<Work> Works { get; set; }

#nullable enable
        [NotMapped]
        public virtual Death? Death { get; set; }
#nullable disable
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace DataService {

    public class DataContext: DbContext {
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Death> Deaths { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Work> Works { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

            optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information);
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(Configuration.Shared.GetDatabaseString());
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(builder => {
                builder.ToTable("person");
                builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("nconst");
                builder.Property(x => x.FirstName).HasColumnName("firstname");
                builder.Property(x => x.LastName).HasColumnName("lastname");
                builder.Property(x => x.BirthYear).HasColumnName("birthyear");
                builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
                builder.HasMany(x => x.Works).WithOne(x => x.Person).HasForeignKey(x => x.PersonId);
                builder.HasOne(x => x.Death).WithOne(x => x.Person).HasForeignKey<Death>(x => x.PersonId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Death>(builder => {
                builder.ToTable("death");
                builder.Property(x => x.PersonId).HasColumnName("nconst");
                builder.Property(x => x.DeathYear).HasColumnName("deathyear");
                builder.HasKey(x => x.PersonId);
                builder.HasOne(x => x.Person).WithOne(x => x.Death).HasForeignKey<Person>(x => x.Id);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Work>(builder => {
                builder.ToTable("_work");
                builder.Property(x => x.TitleId).HasColumnName("tconst");
                builder.Property(x => x.PersonId).HasColumnName("nconst");
                builder.Property(x => x.Job).HasColumnName("job");
                builder.HasKey(x => new { x.TitleId, x.PersonId, x.Job });
                builder.HasOne(x => x.Title).WithMany(x => x.Staff).HasForeignKey(x => x.TitleId);
                builder.HasOne(x => x.Person).WithMany(x => x.Works).HasForeignKey(x => x.PersonId);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can fetch the `Person` instance but its virtual properties are all `null`. I know it has something to do with the foreign keys in `DataContext` but I can't figure it out... What am I missing ?

The `Person` fetch action

```cs
public Person GetPerson(string Id) {
    return Context.Persons.Find(Id);
}
```

The failing test:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test_GetDeath() {
    var person = DataService.GetPerson("nm0113225");
     Assert.NotNull(person);
     Assert.NotNull(person.Death); // <---- Failure
     Assert.Equal("2004", person.Death.DeathYear);
}
```

[image: The result I'm supposed to get]

PS: I know some of the DB attributes might be improved but I can't right now.

PS2: It's not a full version of my code, I have removed objects useless for my question.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You  have to  show the action  are  you using for fetch

Comment: @Serge sorry, updated it. It's a simple Context.Persons.Find(Id)

Comment: Have you heard about `Include`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes indeed but it didn't work at the time I tried it a few days ago... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add include to your query

```
  Context.Persons. Include(i=>i.Works).FirstOrDefault(i=> i.Id==id );
```

and if your remove [NotMapped] from Death, and add Death Id

```
      public int DeathId  { get; set; }
      public virtual Death Death { get; set; }
```

and fix your Death class , I believe that one person can have only one death

```
 public class Death {
         [Key]
         public string Id {get; set;}

        [StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 4)]
        public string DeathYear { get; set; }
       
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }
```

you can use this query

```
Context.Persons.Include(i=>i.Works).Include(i=>i.Death).FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Id==id);
```

Comment: Person is null when I add `Include` to the action

Comment: @AlexisChoupault Sorry it was typo, try   i.Id==id

Comment: no it was me: it seems to work when I remove bidirectional foreign keys into unidirectional ones. Thank you !